# Como retornar os registros dos últimos 7 dias contando o dia atual com o postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Estou fazendo uma busca no banco de dados onde eu quero retornar os registros dos últimos sete dias. Fiz um script SQL que me retorna os registros dos ultimos 7 dias mas ele não conta o dia atual como sendo o primeiro dia dos 7. Por exemplo se eu adicionar um novo item na tabela com a data de hoje e executar o script ele só vai me mostrar esse novo registro quando o mesmo estiver completado um dia. Segue o script:

```
SELECT * FROM postagem_pagina WHERE postagem_pagina.data_postagem BETWEEN CURRENT DATE - 7 AND CURRENT DATE
```

Comment: Não tenho experiência com postgresql, mas este parece ser aquele caso clássico onde o campo data contém também a hora e a query ignora isso.  
Por exemplo, no banco `data_postagem = '03/11/2015 14:00'` (duas da tarde de hoje) e, na query, `CURRENT DATE = '03/11/2015'` (ou seja, equivalente a `'03/11/2015 00:00'` ou seja, o começo do dia de hoje, o que deixa de fora o registro inserido mais tarde).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caso não precise informar um limite de tempo, pode buscar tudo que for posterior ao dia atual -7

```
select * from postagem_pagina where data_postagem > current_date - interval '7 days'
```